# Fix text on an image in css

Tags: html, css

I need to display a string on an image on a fixed position. My code is as follows:

HTML code:

```
<div>
          <img id='flower' src="http://cs-server.usc.edu:45678/hw/hw3/images/main.jpg" alt="Flower"> </img>
          <div id='title' style='margin-top: -19px;'>
          <h2><span id='yellow_text'>Yellow </span><span id='flower_text'>Flower<span></h2>
          <h3><span id='author_name'>A site by Brian Calhoun</span></h3>
        </div>
```

Css code:

```
#flower{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

I need the text in under the `#title` tag to always display at a particular position on the image #flower

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use of  `position absolute;`.

If you wrap your image in a div (which creates a `position: relative` container for our title to be positioned within), like so:

```
<div>
     <div class="image_wrapper">
        <img id='flower' src="http://cs-server.usc.edu:45678/hw/hw3/images/main.jpg" alt="Flower"> </img>
        <div id='title'>
            <h2><span id='yellow_text'>Yellow </span><span id='flower_text'>Flower<span></h2>
            <h3><span id='author_name'>A site by Brian Calhoun</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply these styles:

```
.image_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /* this will center the image in the container */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px; /* adjust as desired */
    left: 15px; /* adjust as desired */
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I wouldn't assume that wrapper was available for styling this way, plus it has no id / class, so there's no way to address it specifically in css.

Comment: @cale_b inline-block is causing display issues with the image

Comment: @cale_b The image was originally displayed in the center. Now it is getting displayed on the extreme left of the page due to the inline-block. No display block doesnt fix the original problem.

Comment: Please see the edit I made - added `margin: 0 auto;` to the div.  This will allow the image to center - ASSUMING that the parent container has `text-align: center` on it.

Comment: @cale_b This was pretty close but the text still drifts to the right

Comment: What do you mean "the text drifts..."?  You can put it exactly where you want it with the top / left values...